# AudioKit crashes when try record after playing in AKPlayer

Tags: swift, audiokit

Here’s the problem I have. I have an app that loads sounds from the web and plays it afterward. At the same time, the app has the feature to record voice and play it. I use two different View Controllers for these two features. For these tasks, I’ve created a singleton.

When I launch the app and go directly to the Record View Controller first - everything works fine (I can record the sound, play it, then I can go to my second View Controller with my sounds and can play it with no problems too).

However, if I launch the app and play the sounds FIRST (use my second view controller) and after this go to Record View Controller and try to record something I get this crash with the message : `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: '[[busArray objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)element] setFormat:format error:&nsErr]: returned false, error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10865 "(null)"'`

This crash happens when I taped recordButton. It happens on line - try recorder.record():

```
func startRecord() {
    if AKSettings.headPhonesPlugged {
        micBooster.gain = 1
    }
    micBooster.gain = 0
    do {
        try recorder.record()
    } catch {
        print("Can't record because: \(error)")
    }
}
```

This crash happens if I set category .playAndRecord

```
try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
```

My singleton class:

```
class AudioKitSingleton {
var mic: AKMicrophone!
var micMixer: AKMixer!
var recorder: AKNodeRecorder!
var tape: AKAudioFile!
var player: AKPlayer!
var micBooster: AKBooster!
var mainMixer: AKMixer!
var url: URL?
var name: String?
var artist: String?
var uploader: String?
var performer: String?
var load: Bool = false
var isPlay: Bool = false
var categoryID: Int? = nil

static let shared = AudioKitSingleton()

func initMic() {
    stopAudioKitEngine()
    AKAudioFile.cleanTempDirectory()
    AKSettings.bufferLength = .medium
    AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
    setupRecordSession()
    mic = AKMicrophone()
    micMixer = AKMixer(mic)
    micBooster = AKBooster(micMixer)
    micBooster.gain = 0
    recorder = try? AKNodeRecorder(node: micMixer)
    if let file = recorder.audioFile {
        player = AKPlayer(audioFile: file)
    }
    player.isLooping = false
    mainMixer = AKMixer(player, micBooster)
    AudioKit.output = mainMixer
    startAudioKitEngine()
}

func deinitMic() {
    stopAudioKitEngine()
    mic = nil
    micMixer = nil
    recorder = nil
    tape = nil
    player = nil
    micBooster = nil
    mainMixer = nil
}

func startRecord() {
    if AKSettings.headPhonesPlugged {
        micBooster.gain = 1
    }
    micBooster.gain = 0
    do {
        try recorder.record()
    } catch {
        print("Can't record because: \(error)")
    }
}

func stopRecord() {
    micBooster.gain = 0
    tape = recorder.audioFile!
    player.load(audioFile: tape)
    player.prepare()
    if let _ = player.audioFile?.duration {
        recorder.stop()
    }
}

func resetRecorder() {
    do {
        try recorder.reset()
    } catch {
        print("Can't reset recorder because: \(error)")
    }
}

func playerPlayRecord() {
    player.play()
}

func playerStopRecord() {
    player.stop()
}

func setupRecordSession() {
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(.record, mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func startAudioKitEngine() {
    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
    } catch {
        AKLog("AudioKit did not start because: \(error)")
    }
}

func stopAudioKitEngine() {
    if AudioKit.engine.isRunning {
        do {
            try AudioKit.stop()
        } catch {
            AKLog("AudioKit did not start because: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

func setupPlayer(url: URL) {
    if AudioKit.engine.isRunning {
    stopAudioKitEngine()
    }
    player = try AKPlayer(url: url)
    AudioKit.output = player
    startAudioKitEngine()
}

func setupPlayer(mixloop: AVAudioFile) {
    if AudioKit.engine.isRunning {
    stopAudioKitEngine()
    }
    player = try AKPlayer(audioFile: mixloop)
    AudioKit.output = player
    startAudioKitEngine()
}

func play() {
    try player?.play()
}

func resume() {
    try player?.resume()
}

func stop() {
    player?.stop()
}

func pause() {
    player?.pause()
}

func remove() {
    if AudioKit.engine.isRunning {
        try? AudioKit.stop()
        player?.stop()
        player = nil
        recorder = nil
        AudioKit.output = nil
        url = nil
        name = nil
        artist = nil
        uploader = nil
        load = false
        isPlay = false
    }
}
```

}

This crash happens on all iPhones except iPhone 5s, iOS12. Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this will be solved in today's AudioKit 4.5.2 release, uploading now.